# Function pointer as parameter of qsort function

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

at the qsort function in c there is a functin pointer to the compare function, which actually sorts the data of the array given.

so inside that function i see:

```
if ( *(MyType*)a <  *(MyType*)b ) return -1;
```

Well i understand a will casted to MyType* but what about the star after that on the very left? what is it doing?

Well, i guess this just dereference the pointer a?

thx.

/me

Comment: You should not add answers that are not really answers.

Comment: yeah. its just a wild guess i can remove it when its proven to be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well i understand a will casted to MyType* but what about the star
>   after that on the very left? what is it doing?

So you know `a` is a pointer and pointer holds some valid memory location the value stored in that memory location is fetched by using the `*` operator which is called Dereferencing a pointer